# Invalid use of group function - #1111

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Table verkoper

[image]

Table bestellingen

[image]

My Query:

```
  SELECT v.naam, 
         SUM(COUNT(b.status) * 1.50)
    FROM verkoper AS v INNER JOIN 
         bestellingen AS b ON b.verkoper = v.id
   WHERE b.status = 'retour'
GROUP BY b.verkoper
```

It gives me the error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`
Anyone an idea?

Comment: You can not select columns that are not part of the grouping (here: v.naam)

Comment: Aggregate inside an aggregate isn't allowed I guess. Also Mysql allows this weird way to write `group by` so we cannot guess what you are trying to achieve. Can you add your expected result

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will return an error with newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and an unpredictable result with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
SELECT v.naam, COUNT(*)*1.50
FROM verkoper v INNER JOIN
     bestellingen b
     ON b.verkoper = v.id
WHERE b.status = 'retour'
GROUP BY v.naam;
```

Notes:

- The `GROUP BY` keys should match the unaggregated columns in the query.
- You can count all rows using `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`.  This is simpler to type.
- There is no reason to nest `COUNT()` inside `SUM()`.

Comment: OMG! Thanks, this is so stupid of me... Didn't even tried it